# Does tor browser open a new circuit for each unique website?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, circuit

What is the limit of circuits. For example if I open 100 unique domains will TOR make 100 different circuits or does this have some upper limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Tor Browser, every domain gets it's own circuit. [The Design and Implementation of the Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/#identifier-linkability) document has some more details on it.

Frankly, you get an own circuit for every domain shown in the address bar. So, if you visit google.com a different circuit is used than when you visit example.com even when content, like an advertisement, is loaded from google.com.

I do not believe that there is a limit or at least not one you're likely to ever hit.

Comment: Is there any downside to using a circuit for each domain? Like performance wise or security wise? Because the default tor daemon only opens 5 circuits and the number of circuits does not exceed that number.

Comment: There can be a slight performance hit because you need to build more circuits but Tor builds spare circuits that can be used when you visit a different domain making it pretty efficient. Security should be better since it is harder to correlate the traffic to the user when traffic I split among many exits. Tor exceeds 5 circuits here, how did you measure/observe the 5 circuits?